# Export from database table to CSV file

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to export data from a database table to CSV file using following script:

```
USE DATABASE;

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Text;Database=C:\TEMP\;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited',
'SELECT * FROM [CSV_TEST.csv]')
SELECT [ColumnA]
      ,[ColumnB]
      ,[ColumnC]
FROM dbo.CSV_TEST;
```

The CSV file is located under C:\TEMP directory on database server, also has exact same filename and columns as CSV_TEST table. When I run the query, I get following errors. Would be great if you have ideas how to resolve them! Many thanks in advance...

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation.
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" could not INSERT INTO table "[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0]".
```

Comment: The syntax looks good. The first error message says `Database or object is read-only`. I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update csv using `OPENROWSET`.

If you want to export your query result to csv, use `bcp` utility.

For example:

```
bcp "SELECT [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC] FROM dbo.CSV_TEST" queryout C:\TEMP\CSVTEST.csv -S <YourSQLServerNAme> -d <YourDatebaseName> -c -t, -T
```

If you want to execute above from Stored Procedure or SQL Query, you need to use SP  `xp_cmdshell`

For example:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC] FROM dbo.CSV_TEST" queryout C:\TEMP\CSVTEST.csv -S <YourSQLServerName> -d <YourDatebaseName> -c -t, -T'
```

Expore more about [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#T) and [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as per your need.